# Return error to callback in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code:

```
User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    //blah blah
});
```

The `findById` method is defined in the `User` module. It looks like this:

```
exports.findById = function(id,callback) {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM usertable", function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            callback(rows);
        });
}
```

As the callback to the `findById()` method takes two parameters, namely, `err` and `user`, I'm wondering if I've defined the function in a proper way. Will the code work or do I have to pass the parameters to the callback in a different way?

Comment: you need to call the callback with 2 args: `callback(err, rows);`

Comment: or change `User.findById(id, function(err, user) {` to `User.findById(id, function(user) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get an error, you need to pass `err` to the callback, otherwise pass `null` as the first parameter and then your `rows`:

```
exports.findById = function(id,callback) {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM usertable", function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) return callback( err );
            return callback(null, rows);
        });
}
```

Alternatively, since you aren't doing any transformations/modifications in your `connection.query` callback, you can just pass the `findById` callback straight through to `connection.query`:

```
exports.findById = function(id,callback) {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM usertable", callback);
}
```